# Appropriate way to concat JSON files with Grunt

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I'm looking for the best way to combine json files maintaining certain structure using Grunt.

The files are disposed in folders in a structure like this:

```
App
├── locales
│   ├── en
│   │   └── translation.json
│   ├── es
│   │   └── translation.json
│   └── fr
│       └── translation.json
└── widgets
    ├── Posts
    │   └── locales
    │       ├── en
    │       │   └── translation.json
    │       ├── es
    │       │   └── translation.json
    │       └── fr
    │           └── translation.json
    ├── Comments
    │   └── locales
    │       ├── en
    │       │   └── translation.json
    │       ├── es
    │       │   └── translation.json
    │       └── fr
    │           └── translation.json
    └── Links
        ├── locales
        │   ├── en
        │   │   └── translation.json
        │   ├── es
        │   │   └── translation.json
        │   └── fr
        │       └── translation.json
```

And the desired output with the files merged would be:

```
App
│
├── lang
│   ├── en
│   │   └── translation.json
│   ├── es
│   │   └── translation.json
│   └── fr
│       └── translation.json
├── locales
└── widgets
```

So far I came up with one solution using grunt-contrib-concat, but I think there should be a better way to do it.

```
concat: {
  translateEN: {
    src: [
      'www/js/app/locales/en/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/posts/locales/en/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/comments/locales/en/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/links/locales/en/*.json'
    ],
    dest: 'www/js/app/lang/en/translation.json',
    options: {
      banner: '{',
      footer: "}",
      separator: ','
    }
  },
  translateES: {
    src: [
      'www/js/app/locales/es/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/posts/locales/es/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/comments/locales/es/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/links/locales/es/*.json'
    ],
    dest: 'www/js/app/lang/es/translation.json',
    options: {
      banner: '{',
      footer: "}",
      separator: ','
    }
  },
  translateFR: {
    src: [
      'www/js/app/locales/fr/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/posts/locales/fr/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/comments/locales/fr/*.json',
      'www/js/app/widgets/links/locales/fr/*.json'
    ],
    dest: 'www/js/app/lang/fr/translation.json',
    options: {
      banner: '{',
      footer: "}",
      separator: ','
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly should be better?

Comment: You can use something like `www/js/app/**locales/en/*.json` to keep your code smaller but I'm not even sure if thats the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writting my own grunt task for this:

```
  grunt.task.registerMultiTask('buildLocales', 'Build Locale files.', function() {
    var that = this,
        len = this.filesSrc.length,
        outputDir,
        outputFile,
        originalFile,
        destFile,
        merged;

    var jsonConcat = function(object1, object2) {
      var key, a1, a2;
      for (key in object2) {
        if (object2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          a2 = object2[key];
          a1 = object1[key];
          if (a1) {
            a1.push.apply(a1, a2);
          } else {
            object1[key] = a2;
          }
        }
      }

      return object1;
    };

    var iterateTroughFiles = function(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename){
      if (abspath.indexOf('/.svn') === -1){
        outputDir = that.data.dest + '/' + subdir;
        outputFile = outputDir + '/' + filename;

        // If output dir doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!grunt.file.exists(outputDir)) {
          grunt.file.mkdir(outputDir);
        }

        originalFile = grunt.file.readJSON(abspath);

        // if dest file doenst exist, then just copy it.
        if (!grunt.file.exists(outputFile)) {
          grunt.file.write(outputFile, JSON.stringify(originalFile));
        } else {
          // read source file, read dest file. merge them. write it in dest file
          destFile = grunt.file.readJSON(outputFile);

          merged = jsonConcat(destFile, originalFile);

          grunt.file.write(outputFile, JSON.stringify(merged));
        }
      }
    };

    for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
      grunt.file.recurse(this.filesSrc[x], iterateTroughFiles);
    }
  });
```

And the implementation is something like this:

```
buildLocales: {
  locales:{
    src: [
      'www/js/app/**/locales'
    ],
    dest: PATH_BUILD_LANGUAGES
  }
},
```

Comment: Have you published this as a grunt plugin? could be useful to others